# Releasing android library with support library dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-library

I'm about to publish an Android library that depends on `appcompat`. It doesn't depend on any particular version of it.

When I build the library and release it to `bintray`, the resulting `pom` contains this dependency with a specific version used to build the library.

When I try to import the library in other application,

```
implementation 'com.ezaquarii:ezpermission:1.0.1'
```

gradle complains:

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different
>   version for the compile (26.0.2) and runtime (26.1.0) classpath. You
>   should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Well, that's hardly to be unexpected, but how can I build the library, so that it doesn't complain when you have a newer version of `appcompat`?

I can use exclude:

```
implementation ('com.mylibrary:library:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

but this is additional overhead for users who use my library. I'd like to exclude the support group by default.

Full library source code:
https://github.com/ezaquarii/EzPermission

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The instruction explicitly asks to exclude support library.